# What is the purpose of the resistor between the p_in+ and p_out of the Op-Amp in this circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, power-sequencing

I found a very interesting sequence biasing circuit.
https://www.qorvo.com/products/d/da007774

I understand how it works by now. But I still do not understand why there is a 1 Meg resistor (R7) between the out and + pins of the Op-amp U3?

I believe it is there to make sure that the voltage of the -IN is higher than +IN in the beginning so the output of the opamp would be 0. However, it is possible to connect the 1 MEG to the ground rather than the output. Why should we connect the 1 MEG to the output?
Isn't thermal noise a problem in the positive feedback?
I believe I do not know some essential trick.
I ask this question because people act weird when they see feedback to the +IN of the opamp.

Schematic:

[image]

Comment: Post a schematic not a whole PDF file.

Comment: U3 is a comparator and the resistor R7 is to give small hysteresis. Have a look: https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu020a/tidu020a.pdf?ts=1623159514656&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Comment: Circuit looks pretty dodgy to me. Power-up state of U3 with REG = /POWER_VALID high-Z?

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry.

Comment: @Mike Actually, I was reading about it and I faced Schmitt trigger. I recalled some lessons. Thank you.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I do not understand what exactly you mean. If you mean to power up the U3 with the power valid then I say it is not a good idea since the power valid of the U2 goes down and also the power valid/ good is an open drain. It is only beneficial for sending flags.

Comment: POWER_VALID will be invalid (open) on a clean power-up so both inputs will be close to the same voltage, modulo the hysteresis and whatever goes on inside U3 as the power rail becomes valid. Non-clean power-up/power down may be issues.